# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore class IdentityUser is empty, shouldn't it be full?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I have added a Nugget package Identity.frameworkcore to my project and I have used the `IdentityUser` class, but it seems that it is empty.
[image]

I am also looking at the tutorial  and in there it seems that the class is quite full 
[image]

Any tips?

Comment: `IdentityUser ` is not empty - it inherits from `IdentityUser<TKey>`. And you can start learning here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: @trailmax  Ohh.... Thank you very much. :)